# Bounded Function Which is Not Riemann Integrable

Tags: measure-theory, derivatives, examples-counterexamples, riemann-integration

*This problem is taken from Problem 2.4.31 (page 84) from [Problems in Mathematical Analysis: Integration](http://books.google.com/books?id=OBK7D1qcY0oC&pg=PA84&lpg=PA84&dq=%22Give+an+example+of+a+bounded+function%22+%22which+is+not+Riemann+Integrable,+but+is+a+derivative+of+some+function%22&source=bl&ots=JgTTEAPY3o&sig=4qcimfqsmlE-5EWKVuEJFlapn7A&hl=en&ei=1UNoTM_3I4OYuAOMvKD-Aw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CBYQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Give%20an%20example%20of%20a%20bounded%20function%22%20%22which%20is%20not%20Riemann%20Integrable%2C%20but%20is%20a%20derivative%20of%20some%20function%22&f=false) by W. J. Kaczor, Wiesława J. Kaczor and Maria T. Nowak.*

---

Give an example of a bounded function $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ which is not Riemann Integrable, but is a derivative of some function $g$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Have you seen [Volterra's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function)?

Comment: @Akhil Matthew: Yes i did have a look. But out of ideas.

Comment: @Chandru: what's lacking? Volterra's function has exactly the properties you request.  @Akhil: the link is wrong.

Comment: @Akhil, @Nate: I fixed the link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I gave an answer to this question on Math Overflow some months ago:

[Integrability of derivatives](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6711/integrability-of-derivatives/6716#6716)

See, in particular, [this](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/Goffman77.pdf) paper: Goffman, Casper A bounded derivative which is not Riemann integrable. Amer. Math. Monthly 84 (1977), no. 3, 205--206.

Comment: The university link is broken, however.  I found a copy on [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2319494) instead.