# Sufficient condition(s) for $f'$ to be Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, riemann-integration

Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable on $[0,1]$. We know that the derivative of $f$ denoted by $f'$ may not be Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$.

We know that a necessary condition for $f'$ to be Riemann integrable is boundedness of $f'$ on $[0,1]$.

My question:

1. Is boundedness of $f'$ on $[0,1]$ also a sufficient condition?
2. What are other sufficient conditions of $f'$ to be Riemann integratble on $[0,1]$?

Comment: A related post: [Bounded Function Which is Not Riemann Integrable](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2292). The answer posted there links to this post on [mathoverflow.se]: [Integrability of derivatives](https://mathoverflow.net/q/6711),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, boundeness of $f'$ is not a sufficient condition. There are differentiable functions (such as [Volterra's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function)) which are differentiable with bounded derivative whose derivative is not Riemann integrable.

Answer (score 1):

The two necessary and sufficient conditions for a function $g:[a, b]\to \Bbb R$ to be Riemann integrable are

- $g$ is bounded
- $g$ is continuous almost everywhere

If $g$ happens to be a derivative $f'$, that doesn't change these requirements. Either may be broken by $f'$.