# Is $f'(x)$ Riemann integrable if it is bounded

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity, riemann-integration, bounded-variation

The fact that $f(x)$ is differetiable dosen't guarantee the integrability of $f'(x)$ on $[a,b]$ beacuse $f'(x)$ could be unbounded, which violates the assumption of Riemann integral. However, what's the case if $f'(x)$ is bounded? Since $f'(x)$ doesn't have any discontinuity point of the first kind and $f'(x)$ is bounded, $f'(x)$ has only discontinuity points as $\sin \frac1x$ dose near $x=0$ if there are any.

Could $f'(x)$ has uncountably many discontinuity points of that kind? Otherwise, $f'(x)$ should be integrable on $[a,b]$. I think $f'(x)$ is integrable if it is bounded, could someone please give me a hand here? Or is there a counterexample?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes. The standard example is [Volterra's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function).

Comment: Thank you, it helps me a lot.

Comment: I can post my comment as an answer, if you want it.

Comment: I am new to this community, what's the difference if you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: So that the question doesn't remain unanswered.

Comment: Oh, sure then so I can check this question. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are differentiable functions $f$ such that $f'$ is bounded but not Riemann-integrable. The standard example is [Volterra's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function).

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3259697/42969?

Comment: @MartinR Sure. I missed that.